# using vaiable as operator in php

Tags: php, operators

I am trying to do this:

```
$identifier_1 = ">";
$identifier_2 = ">";
$relation = "and";

if($value $identifier_1 3 $relation $value $identifier_1 300)
```

which will represent:

```
if($value > 3 and $value > 300)
```

Comment: How would PHP know which are operators and which are variables to compare?

Comment: i am guessing that you can't since language constructs (reserved words) are expected in the BOOLEAN_EXPR of an if(BOOL_EXPR)

Comment: You can use eval() to run code stored in a string, but I would highly discourage this. It's bad for performance (forces the script to be recompiled) and poses a possible security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically three ways.

I. Use eval. This is a powerful option, but also quite dangerous when user input is involved.

```
$op1 = ">";
$op2 = ">";
$op3 = "and";

$expr = "100 $op1 200 $op3 300 $op2 200";
eval("\$result = $expr;");
```

II. Use functions instead of operators

```
function more($a, $b) { return $a > $b; }
function less($a, $b) { return $a < $b; }
function _and($a, $b) { return $a && $b; }

$op1 = 'more';
$op2 = 'less';
$op3 = '_and';

$result = $op3($op1(100, 200), $op2(200, 300));
```

III. Write a parser and evaluate expressions on your own. This is somehow the "cleanest" way of doing this, but can be quite tricky to program - depends on which operators you want to support.